# Magento nav not displaying

Tags: magento, navigation

I am developing a new store in CE 1.7.0.2.

I have about 130 categories so far, all placed under a `root category`.

The `root category` is also defined in `Ststem -> Magage Stores -> Our Store -> Root Category`

If I access the Category pages directly, I can see all products and sub categories in breadcrumbs etc, so I know my structure is correct.  I know I am missing something simple.

I am using the the `modern` template for now until I get the site functional, so all the files are original.

**EDIT** I should also mention that the `System -> Config -> Catalog -> Category Top Navigation -> Maximal Depth` is set to `1`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you cleared cached?

Comment: Cache is disabled -- all have been cleared and indexes run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK --  After many hours of searching I finally figured it out.  If you export your products via any script (mine was custom built -- I exported from CE 1.3.2.4) and import them to a later version (1.7.0.2), even though the import goes smoothly, the values for certain things might not make the transition as smoothly.  Even though I had set my root category for my store view, my products were not applied to a store.  As a result they were there, but not there.

My solution:  `Catalog -> Manage Products -> Select all -> Actions -> Update Attributes -> Submit` ..  Once there check your `Websites` tab.  Make sure to "check" your main website button, and click save.  Run a full reindex and clear cache (I use SSH and `sudo rm -R *` inside /var/cache and /var/session directory).

I hope this helps others who have run into the same issue.

Thank you Moldovan Gheorghe Dani for your answer -- Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried on my local environment with same version of magento and theme, and i have no problem at all.
I noticed that when you create a new category "Is Active" flag is set to No by default, so make sure that is set to Yes, and "Include in Navigation Menu" is also set to Yes for all categories. If still not work try to refresh cache even if is disabled, and indexes also. I hope that it will help you.

Comment: All categories are set to Is Active "yes" -- It was a category/product import and most are set to "yes" in the `include in Navigation Menu`  --  We have a few "experimental" categories that we don't want show, so those are set to "no"